# What to do with my (accidently) sour saison?

Tags: beer, off-flavor, sour

I have recently made a batch of Saison that turned sour. I'm having a hard time pouring it all down the drain, I thought about using it for cooking but I don't know what sort of recipes to look for.
Does anybody have any idea what else I can do with that batch?

Comment: I am currently experiencing a similar issue, but the taste is not really off putting. What's the consensus on whether or not its safe to drink?

Comment: I already drunk a few and l'm fine, I'll keep you updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to cook with it you could try making something akin to a [Flemish stew](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/user/4862541/recipe/stoofvlees-flemish-beef-stew), this usually calls for a darker sour beer, but I imagine it could work well with a sour Saison.

Just don't add the vinegar to the recipe, most people these days make the stew with a Dubbel and add vinegar, rather than using a Flemish Red such as Rodenbach.

Answer (score 6):

As a suggestion:

Heat your beer to 70 deg. Celcius (sorry, I'm metric and don't do Church-of-England units but I'm sure you can convert it to Farenheit yourself) in order to kill yeast and  bacterial infection. About 10 mins at 70 deg. C should do the trick. This will also decarbonate your beer.

Cool as quickly as possible, and watch out for hot side aeration!! Once cool, oxygenate, add yeast nutrient, then add pasteurized fruit juice or fresh fruit pulp, re-pitch a low-attenuation, Belgian style yeast (Fermentis S-33 should do) and let ferment. You should end up with a decent Belgian fruit ale. Use fruits that are high in sweetness and flavor. Strawberry, peach or sweet cherries could work well.

Answer (score 2):

Sourness is essentially acidity, you might try taking a little sample and adding CaCO3 until pH is about 5.9 then tasting it. I tried this on an accidentally soured saison and it made it a bit more drinkable.